# getting the CDF of a RV Y={A/X, B} when X is non-negative continuous RV and A,B are +ve constant?

Tags: probability, random-variables

How do I get the CDF of the random variable Y that is defined as `Y=min{A/X , B}`. When X is non-negative continuous RV and A and B are positive constant.

I know that the solution will start with

```
Fy(y)
= Pr{Y<=y} 
= Pr{min{A/X , B}<=y} 
= ∫ (Pr{min{A/X , B}<=y} fx(x))dx
```

but I have a problem deciding the interval for the integration. since now there are 2 possibilities. 
the way I understand it is :

1. B is the minimum in which the intervals from 0 to B
2. A/X is the minimum in the intervals from 0 to A/X

However, this is not the case to what I have. but instead: 
the 1st integration from 0 to A/B and the 2nd from A/B to infinity

```
=∫ (Pr{B<=y |X=x} fx(x))dx + ∫ (Pr{A/X <=y |X=x} fx(x))dx
```

can someone explain why this is the case??

Answer (score 1):

It is because by definition,

$$ \min\left\{\frac {a} {X}, b \right\} = 
\begin{cases} 
\displaystyle \frac {a} {X} & \text{if} & \displaystyle \frac {a} {X} \leq b
\iff X \geq \frac {a} {b}\\
b & \text{if} & \displaystyle \frac {a} {X} > b
\iff X < \frac {a} {b}
\end{cases}$$